# Java how to create geotiff from points

Tags: raster, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I have an array of objects where each object has three fields: lat, lon, and category. It is essentially pixels that have been given a land use category. I cannot figure out how to turn this data into a geotiff. I assume I should use geotools. The coordinates are in dec degrees lat long. I know I can use q or arcgis to do this but I need to do it as part of an automated process. Just need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use GeoTools for this, you will also probably want to look at a relsted project [JAITools](http://jaitools.org/) which does helpful things with rasters. I wrote some code a while back to [rasterize circles](https://code.google.com/p/spatial-cluster-detection/source/browse/trunk/cluster/src/main/java/org/geotools/clustering/QuantizeCircle.java) on to a Grid and output them as GeoTiffs which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks you @iant, I will mark as answered. Don't have time to try right now but your code looks adaptable to what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for how to actually write the GridCoverage2D to disk as a tif file?